# Postin gitlab issue

Tags: api, gitlab

I have a POST request like that for gitlab

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/4067343/issues?title=Issues%20with%20auth&labels=bug?private_token=MY_PRIVATE_TOKEN
```

but the only thing that i have is:

> {"message":"401 Unauthorized"}

Task is to open issue on the project.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Check is the userid or the Authorisation with which you are trying to access is valid...

Comment: According to official documents there is no need of id or something like that. I change curl command "curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/4/issues?title=Issues%20with%20auth&labels=bug"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GitLab authentication](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#authentication) mentions [private tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#private-tokens) used [as an header or query string](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#basic-usage)

```
curl "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK"
```

But that does not mean you have to use a second `?`, you should separate those query strings with `&`

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/4067343/issues?title=Issues%20with%20auth&labels=bug&private_token=MY_PRIVATE_TOKEN
                                                                                      ^^^
```

See [Query String structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure).

Comment: Not directly a comment, but are you aware by any chane how to restore deleted issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629896/how-to-restore-accidentally-deleted-gitlab-issue

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev No, I am not. I suppose GitLab support would have some elements. Is this a private hosted GitLab server, or gitlab.com?

Comment: No, a public one: https://gitlab.com/publishing-reform/discussion/issues/97

Comment: Well.. it should be a soft delete (https://gitlab.com/dblessing/gitlab-ce/commit/4a1680261513926f0fa4634bae02e8d599d47050), so GitLab support should be able to restore it.

Comment: Oh that is good to hear, anywhere I can find the information how to do it? Or ask for it? It is an important community non-profit project, any help is appreciated!