# How to restore accidentally deleted Gitlab issue?

Tags: gitlab, restore, issue-tracking

It seems I have accidentally deleted a Gitlab issue. Is there any way to restore it?

Comment: Have a DB backup, restore it. If not it is gone for good unless you can retrieve the original issue content from the logs.

Comment: @djuarez
Is there DB backup for Gitlab issues? Any help how to view the logs?